# Java – How to export or generate a True Type Font from custom made glyphs?

Tags: java, fonts, graphics2d, truetype

Is is possible to export a bunch of Graphics2D shapes to a ttf? In other words, how can i use the vector informations to generate such a file? How to compile a font in general? I know this is a huge and complex topic, but some hints would be nice. thx